# В чем смысл HATEOAS?

Tags: rest

Не могу понять смысл HATEOAS в REST API и плюсы его добавления/использования.

Например, пишется API для веб и моб. приложения. Клиентские приложения (веб и моб) "затачиваются" под работу с некоторыми ресурсами API (под ссылки на них).

Не будут же они (веб и моб. приложения) сами "ходить" по ссылкам в ответах и показывать юзеру сырые данные?

Тогда зачем это все надо?

Единственный плюс, который я вижу - это если используя публичный API, мне не придется обращаться к документации, поскольку в ответе я увижу эти ссылки и пойму что можно с ними сделать. Но опять же, я сначала их увижу, а потом заложу функционал для них. А не мой клиент API как-то автоматически увидев ссылки поймет что с ними делать и как их отобразить юзеру (если это что-то немного сложнее CRUD).

Comment: http://spring-projects.ru/understanding/hateoas/

Comment: @VadimBugaiov, хотелось бы услышать практическую пользу от людей, которые использовали Hypermedia в своих API. А эти примерчики со ссылками `self` в любой ссылке выдачи гугл по HATEOAS, но никакой полезной нагрузки не несут.    
П.с. Там в примере ресурс `/product/search` противоречит принципам REST: глаголов в названии ресурса не должно быть. Надо накрайняк так: `/products?search=...`

Comment: думаю таких не много, это как TDD, все слышали, но никто не использовал )))
и по поводу searh, это может быть как и имя существительное "поиск"